# Where am I doing wrong in this SQLite query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Introduction**
I have three tables: Table_ItemDetails, Table_Invoices, Table_PartsTracker.
Table_ItemDetails contains the details of the item, Table_Invoices contains information pertaining to item quantity, while Table_PartsTracker shows which item is used in which project and how much quantity is used. Among all these tables, Item_Number is the foreign key column

**My Objective:**
I need to create a view called View_ItemDetails, that contains the following columns
Item_Number, Item_Name, Item_Description, Total_Qty and Avl_Qty
The total qty is got by adding all the quantities of the item from invoices, while available qty is got by subtracting the items used in project from total qty. I have attached the images of my tables.
To achieve this I have written query like this

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS View_ItemDetails 
AS SELECT 
Table_ItemDetails.Item_Number,
Table_ItemDetails.Item_Name,
Table_ItemDetails.Item_Description,
SUM(Table_Invoices.Qty) as Total_Qty,
(SUM(Table_Invoices.Qty) - ifnull(SUM(Table_PartsTracker.Items_Used), 0)) as Avl_Qty
 FROM Table_ItemDetails  
 OUTER LEFT JOIN Table_Invoices USING(Item_Number)
 OUTER LEFT JOIN Table_PartsTracker USING(Item_Number)
 GROUP BY Table_Invoices.Item_Number
```

but the result in total qty and available qty is wrong. Can someone point me where I am doing wrong?. Thanks

[image: Item Details] [image: Invoices Table] [image: Parts Tracker] [image: View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is because you are doing a cross product between details, invoices, and parts. In other words you are getting every parts row for every invoice row, and summing up all the qty figures for all these combinations.

Since there is not direct relationship between invoice and parts, you need to do the groups independently.

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS View_ItemDetails AS 
SELECT 
    D.Item_Number,
    D.Item_Name,
    D.Item_Description,
    I.Qty as Total_Qty,
    I.Qty - ifnull((P.Items_Used), 0) as Avl_Qty
FROM Table_ItemDetails D 
OUTER LEFT JOIN (select Item_Number, sum(qty) as qty from Table_Invoices group by Item_Number) I USING(Item_Number)
OUTER LEFT JOIN (select Item_Number, sum(Items_Used) as Items_Used from Table_PartsTracker group by Item_Number) P USING(Item_Number)
```